# Saving array data in normalized table

Tags: mysql, arrays, database-design, data-structures, entity-attribute-value

I am updating my user management system with custom user settings feature. In other words, I want to save custom user settings/options in database. Initially I considered serializing the data and saving it to a `TEXT` field. But this has the disadvantage of not being searchable by configuration value.

Hence I have decided to normalize the data and store in a different table. Since the configuration data is multi dimensional, I had to flatten the data. For example,

```
Array (
    [user] => Array (
            [is_developer] => 1
            [api_access] => 1
        )

    [api] => Array (
            [scopes] => Array (
                    [0] => astro
                    [1] => user_info
                )

            [default_scope] => user_info
        )

    [astro] => Array (
            [location_id] => 12345
            [timezone] => America/New_York
            [coordinates] => Array (
                    [latitude] => 12.22
                    [longitude] => 24.44
                )

        )

)
```

is converted to

```
+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| user_id | config                      | value            |
+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|       1 | user.is_developer           | 1                |
|       1 | user.api_access             | 1                |
|       1 | api.scopes                  | astro            |
|       1 | api.scopes                  | user_info        |
|       1 | api.default_scope           | user_info        |
|       1 | astro.location_id           | 12345            |
|       1 | astro.timezone              | America/New_York |
|       1 | astro.coordinates.latitude  | 12.22            |
|       1 | astro.coordinates.longitude | 24.44            |
+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

Is there a better way for storing this data?

**Advantages:**

- Ability to search through custom options, like list all users who are developers and have api access.
- Ability to load just a single option group.
  `SELECT * FROM user_config WHERE config LIKE 'astro.%' AND user_id = 1;`

**Disadvantages:**

- Cannot specify a unique key, since numeric arrays have save config key. If I append the numeric index to the key (`api.scopes.0`, `api.scopes.1` etc), then advantage #1 is partially lost.
- Since unique key is not present, I am not able to use the better performing `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` query. Instead, when the data needs to be updated, I have to delete the existing values and re-insert the data within a transaction.

**Update:**

After reading unique2's answer, I got another idea. Further normalizing the data might solve the unique key issue. i.e., save the keys in one table and the data in another. <del>Need to check if `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` will work with multiple tables.</del> **Insert does not work with multiple tables, so I guess that makes further normalization irrelevant.**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_config;
+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
| config_id | user_id | config                      |
+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
|         1 |       1 | api.default_scope           |
|         2 |       1 | api.scopes                  |
|         3 |       1 | astro.coordinates.latitude  |
|         4 |       1 | astro.coordinates.longitude |
|         5 |       1 | astro.location_id           |
|         6 |       1 | astro.timezone              |
|         7 |       1 | user.api_access             |
|         8 |       1 | user.is_developer           |
+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM user_config_value;
+-----------+------------------+
| config_id | value            |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 | user_info        |
|         2 | astro            |
|         2 | user_info        |
|         3 | 12.22            |
|         4 | 24.44            |
|         5 | 12345            |
|         6 | America/New_York |
|         7 | 1                |
|         8 | 1                |
+-----------+------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Note:**

- *Storing the data in a NOSQL database is not an option.*
- *Actually, this is more of an academic question, because the actual custom data stored is very small and that too for very few users. Hence storing it as a serialized array or loading the entire array is not going to be a huge overhead, in my particular case.*

Answer (score 1):

**Update (see previous version below):**

With both your solution and my previous version there is actually the problem that not all information from your array structure is saved. You can still avoid `api.scopes.1` by putting the last element of the option name in a separate field. If you combine this with soft deletion, you can use `INSERT ... ON DUBLICATE UPDATE`.

```
+----------+-------------------+---------------+------------------+---------+
| user_id* | config_group*     | config*       | value            | deleted |
+----------+-------------------+---------------+------------------+---------+
|        1 | user              | is_developer  | 1                |       0 |
|        1 | user              | api_access    | 1                |       0 |
|        1 | api.scopes        | 1             | astro            |       0 |
|        1 | api.scopes        | 2             | user_info        |       0 |
|        1 | api               | default_scope | user_info        |       0 |
|        1 | astro             | location_id   | 12345            |       0 |
|        1 | astro             | timezone      | America/New_York |       0 |
|        1 | astro.coordinates | latitude      | 12.22            |       0 |
|        1 | astro.coordinates | longitude     | 24.44            |       0 |
+----------+-----------------------------------+------------------+---------+
* marks key columns
```

**Previous version:**

If you split your data in two tables you can use a unique key for each of them.

The first table contains all config options which take on a single value (* marks key columns):

```
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| user_id* | config*                     | value            |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|        1 | user.is_developer           | 1                |
|        1 | user.api_access             | 1                |
|        1 | api.default_scope           | user_info        |
|        1 | astro.location_id           | 12345            |
|        1 | astro.timezone              | America/New_York |
|        1 | astro.coordinates.latitude  | 12.22            |
|        1 | astro.coordinates.longitude | 24.44            |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

The second table contains all options which consist of a set of values (with no dublicates; * marks key columns):

```
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| user_id* | config*                     | value*           |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|        1 | api.scopes                  | astro            |
|        1 | api.scopes                  | user_info        |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

Thus you can use your database to ensure data integrity. `INSERT ... ON DUBLICATE UPDATE` works naturally with the first table. You can also use it with your second table if you are willing to use soft delete:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+
| user_id* | config*                     | value*           | deleted |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+
|        1 | api.scopes                  | astro            |       0 |
|        1 | api.scopes                  | user_info        |       0 |
|        1 | api.scopes                  | old              |       1 |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but splitting values over two tables does not seem to be a good solution. It will make CRUD operations unnecessarily complicated. Further, api.scopes might have a single value one time, multiple values next time. Which means I will have to check both tables, for each operation.

Comment: `api.scopes` should always be in the second table, since it is *allowed* to have more then one value, while this wouldn't make sense for `user.is_developer`. This assumes you know beforehand in which categories a config belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You have reinvented a design called Entity-Attribute-Value. This is *not* what normalization means. Neither of the proposed ideas in your question, nor the proposed solution from @unique2's answer, fit any definition of a normal form -- they're not even relations.

You're correct that unique constraints don't work. Neither do foreign key constraints, or even NOT NULL. For example, how would you make the database enforce a mandatory value for `user.api_access`?

For more discussion on why EAV is a non-relational design, see my blog [EAV FAIL](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html), or many of [my answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:20860%20%5Bentity-attribute-value%5D) for [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) questions.

For alternative solutions to support user-defined attributes, see my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling). I gave an overview of the pros and cons of:

- Extra Columns
- Entity-Attribute-Value
- Class Table Inheritance
- Serialized LOB
- Inverted Indexes